# How to add accelerometer parallax effect in Flutter?

Tags: image, flutter, flutter-layout, parallax, parallax.js

I want to shift background image according to device orientation and angle.

All Flutter parallax implementions which I found were using scrolling events to shift image. But how to do the same using acceleromenter/gyroscope data?

Basically, I'm looking for something similar to parallax.js, but on Flutter.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found a possible solution to my question:
https://github.com/opannapo/Flutter-DemoAccelerometer